# Pwa show always chrome logo in shurtcut

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've recently try to install multiple PWA, but I don't really understand why shurtcut icon have always chrome logo.

I've try 4 PWA installation, 4 this case.

Anyone know if i need to change chrome parameters ?

You can try using this PWA :
https://a2hs.glitch.me/

Thank you !

Comment: Hey, you are testing with the app I made a few years back! Nice. You are trying on Android chrome? It installs for me without the additional Chrome logo.

Comment: Are you putting in HTTPS ? Sometimes Gitch uses HTTP which means it is not a valid PWA. So the Icon you see with the Chrome logo is just a shortcut to the website.